# How Heavy was a Spinning Jenny or Spinning Mule?

Tags: industrial-revolution, industry

The [spinning jenny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_jenny), [water frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_frame) and [spinning mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_mule) were textile spinning frames used during the industrial revolution.

Approximately how heavy were these machines?

Comment: I'm not sure that there was a standard design so there's probably a variety of values.

Comment: Browsing the WIkipedia page confirms @KillingTime's hypothesis.